# Ending the regex correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have an editor where its possible to paste a video url, which I by regex convert to an embed code.

The url in the WYSIWYG-editor is:
http://emedia.is.ed.ac.uk:8080/JW/wsconfig.xml&file=mp4:directory/date_submitted/filename-stream-WSwifi.m4v

The output html is:

```
<p>http://emedia.is.ed.ac.uk:8080/JW/wsconfig.xml&amp;file=mp4:directory/date_submitted/filename-stream-WSwifi.m4v</p>
```

To look for this I use the following regex in JavaScript:

```
/http:\/\/(www.)?emedia.is.ed.ac.uk:8080\/JW\/?(.*)?/
```

But for some reason the match contains the `</p>` aswell on matchgroup 2? How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
http:\/\/(www\.)?emedia\.is\.ed\.ac\.uk:8080\/JW\/?([^<]*)
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?317l9).

Instead of matching any character with `.*` I use `[^<]*`, meaning match anything but "<".

I also removed the `?` at the end since with the `*` quantifier you don't need it, I also escaped all your dots you want to match literally.

Answer (score 0):

In this specific case you can change the last `.` to `[^<\s]`.

```
/http:\/\/(www\.)?emedia\.is\.ed\.ac\.uk:8080\/JW\/?([^<\s]*)/
```

That way the match will stop at the first `<` or space.

Answer (score 0):

The

```
(.*)?
```

At the end swallows your p tag. I would rewrite the regex to

```
http:\/\/(www.)?emedia.is.ed.ac.uk:8080\/JW\/?([^<]*)
```

Now group 2 is clean